# MumbleKit library produces no .a target

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, speex

I included the MumbleKit library in a project and all seems to compile correctly; yet none of the 3dparty libraries, nor main mumblekit library produces its .a target. I even tried compiling 3dparties library Speex individually and again no error, but no target. Another project with seemingly the same configuration produces the .a files without any problem and so I have no cue about what might be wrong in the new one; the following image shows the situation for the two projects after compiling both:[image: Comparing the two projects]

Comment: I tried removing and reinserting MumbleKit, just in case something went wrong in the original installation. Yet I am left worse than before: if I just compile MumbleKit, it does it fine but again does not create any .a library. If instead I compile the whole project I get arc errors on MumbleKit notwithstanding it is set to No Arc.

Comment: Now I managed to compile and link everything, even if the .a libraries keeps on being red. Yet, when I try to use its services, the linker complains bitterly it cannot find several symbols from architecture i386 (I am presently running it on the simulator):
  "_MKAudioDidRestartNotification", referenced from:
      -[MUAdvancedAudioPreferencesViewController viewWillAppear:] in MUAdvancedAudioPreferencesViewController.o
  "_MKCertificateItemCommonName", referenced from:
      -[MUCertificateViewController showDataForCertificate:] in MUCertificateViewController.o and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was apparently to enable the all architectures flag both in the main mumblekit target and in all the dependent ones. The libraries remain red for some strange reasons. Yet everything seems working inclusing the usage of the mumblekit features.